# retrofit - The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am getting all of sudden an error as below.

```
/Users/developer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b85d3ca1d1a3ee19e6a335126cc9759f/transformed/jetified-retrofit-2.10.0.jar!/META-INF/retrofit.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

Project gradle file is as below.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url = 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/AwemeOpenSDK" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app gradle file is as below.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs false  // Paste this line
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
               }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/UnifiedAPI-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/NeptuneLiteApi_V3.25.00_20210706.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'



    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2+'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

}
```

The code was working fine in morning but now in afternoon it's not working.

Any idea what is going wrong?

This is weird behavior. Even retrofit 2.10.0 is not downloaded...

Comment: What is the Kotlin version of your project?

Comment: @tomerpacific : It's 1.7.0.. You can check in gradle file above...